# App could't run on a child-process after upgrade to OSX 10.12

Tags: macos, python-2.7, wxpython

When I upgrade my OSX to 10.12, and I found I couldn't use mavproxy again, because it create map and console process with wxWidgets compoents. From the error report, we can see there add a assertion to avoid "NSApplication run" working on the child process; however the mavproxy need that, how can I save it?

## Following is the error report.

```
Application Specific Information:
BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Assertion failed: Block was expected to execute on queue [com.apple.main-thread]
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffab526b2f _dispatch_assert_queue_fail + 99
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffab51ec9d dispatch_assert_queue + 155
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9449be61 -[NSPersistentUIRestorer restoreStateFromRecords:usingDelegate:completionHandler:] + 192
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff94b3f2a1 -[NSPersistentUIManager restoreAllPersistentStateWithCompletionHandler:] + 272
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff941a775b -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:completionHandler:] + 368
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff942e3504 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 138
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff941a29a3 _DPSNextEvent + 2035
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff948b28eb -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1637
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff94196fbd -[NSApplication run] + 926
9   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.0.dylib 0x00000001094fe2bb wxApp::CallOnInit() + 155
10  _core_.so                       0x0000000108f22c53 wxPyApp::_BootstrapApp() + 803
11  _core_.so                       0x0000000108f85e0e _wrap_PyApp__BootstrapApp(_object*, _object*) + 78
12  org.python.python               0x000000010638610c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13560
13  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
14  org.python.python               0x0000000106389442 0x106300000 + 562242
15  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
16  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
17  org.python.python               0x0000000106328531 0x106300000 + 165169
18  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
19  org.python.python               0x000000010631540c 0x106300000 + 87052
20  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
21  org.python.python               0x0000000106351283 0x106300000 + 332419
22  org.python.python               0x000000010634cad8 0x106300000 + 314072
23  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
24  org.python.python               0x00000001063857eb PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11223
25  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
26  org.python.python               0x0000000106328531 0x106300000 + 165169
27  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
28  org.python.python               0x0000000106386045 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13361
29  org.python.python               0x00000001063894d5 0x106300000 + 562389
30  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
31  org.python.python               0x00000001063894d5 0x106300000 + 562389
32  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
33  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
34  org.python.python               0x0000000106328531 0x106300000 + 165169
35  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
36  org.python.python               0x000000010631540c 0x106300000 + 87052
37  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
38  org.python.python               0x0000000106351283 0x106300000 + 332419
39  org.python.python               0x000000010634cad8 0x106300000 + 314072
40  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
41  org.python.python               0x00000001063857eb PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11223
42  org.python.python               0x00000001063894d5 0x106300000 + 562389
43  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
44  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
45  org.python.python               0x0000000106328531 0x106300000 + 165169
46  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
47  org.python.python               0x000000010631540c 0x106300000 + 87052
48  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
49  org.python.python               0x0000000106388e1b PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 165
50  org.python.python               0x0000000106313687 PyInstance_New + 126
51  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
52  org.python.python               0x00000001063857eb PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11223
53  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
54  org.python.python               0x0000000106328531 0x106300000 + 165169
55  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
56  org.python.python               0x000000010631540c 0x106300000 + 87052
57  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
58  org.python.python               0x0000000106351283 0x106300000 + 332419
59  org.python.python               0x000000010634cad8 0x106300000 + 314072
60  org.python.python               0x000000010630a75b PyObject_Call + 99
61  org.python.python               0x00000001063857eb PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11223
62  org.python.python               0x00000001063894d5 0x106300000 + 562389
63  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
64  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
65  org.python.python               0x0000000106389442 0x106300000 + 562242
66  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
67  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
68  org.python.python               0x0000000106389442 0x106300000 + 562242
69  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
70  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
71  org.python.python               0x0000000106389442 0x106300000 + 562242
72  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
73  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
74  org.python.python               0x0000000106387120 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 17676
75  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
76  org.python.python               0x0000000106389442 0x106300000 + 562242
77  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
78  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
79  org.python.python               0x0000000106389442 0x106300000 + 562242
80  org.python.python               0x0000000106385eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
81  org.python.python               0x0000000106382a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
82  org.python.python               0x00000001063823c7 PyEval_EvalCode + 48
83  org.python.python               0x00000001063a263d 0x106300000 + 665149
84  org.python.python               0x00000001063a26e0 PyRun_FileExFlags + 133
85  org.python.python               0x00000001063a2231 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 702
86  org.python.python               0x00000001063b3bca Py_Main + 3094
87  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffab54a255 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffab6794e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffab7607c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffab760221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffab6794e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffab7607c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffab760221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffab6794e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffab760632 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffab760221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffab6794e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffab7607c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffab760221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000203  rbx: 0x00007fd528e7c6f0  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x000000010645fe08
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007fff59900a80  rsp: 0x00007fff59900a70
   r8: 0x0000000000000008   r9: 0x00000000000007c6  r10: 0x00007fd528e00000  r11: 0x0000000000001400
  r12: 0x00007fd528e7b6a0  r13: 0x00007fd528e7b6a0  r14: 0x00007fff94da212d  r15: 0x00007fff59900f08
  rip: 0x00007fffab526b2f  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00007fffab758943

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6
```